# setOnAction in Controller class results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, javafx

My FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<?import java.lang.*?> 
<?import java.util.*?> 
<?import javafx.scene.*?> 
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?> 
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>  
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"          fx:controller="Test" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
  <CheckBox fx:id="box" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="775.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="527.0" text="Text" />
</AnchorPane>
```

My Controller-Class:

```
public class Test {
  
  @FXML protected CheckBox box;

  public void initialize() {
    box.setOnAction(...);
  }
```

The problem is that i get the following NPE:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.CheckBox.setOnAction(javafx.event.EventHandler)" because "this.box" is null
```

How is this possible when annotated with @FXML?

Im trying to implement this with the new setOnAction implementation instead of using Events defined in FXML.

When using separate onAction-EventHandler it works. But I want to do it without this.

Comment: What is the "new setOnAction implementation"? Post the complete stack trace and a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good solution:**

Please make sure that:

1. Your controller class `implements Initializable`.
2. Your Scene is loaded with the `FXMLLoader`.

**Lifecycle explanation:**

1. When you start your application your controller is generally null and all fields inside too.
2. When your application loads a Scene, then it checks if the Scene has a controller assigned.
3. If the Scene has a controller assigned, the application creates an instance of the assigned controller and assigns it to the Scene.
4. While creating the instance of the controller, it checks, if there are any fields with @FXML annotations.
5. For all @FXML annotated fields, there will be an instance created and assigned to that field. Until now, all fields are null.
6. If your Scene is gone, the garbage collector will destroy the controller, because it is not used anymore (sets it to null)

**Workaround solution 1:**

If you are creating the controller manually with the `new` keyword, you must put `= new CheckBox...` behind your field, because @FXML will not create an instance for you.

**Workaround solution 2:**

If your project has a strange architecture you can try to put your code into `Platform.runLater(Runnable)`.